# jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 + Flot strange loading message

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, flot

I would like to use a flot interactive example with jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 in my project. But with the newest version of jQuery Mobile i'm getting a strange frame around the chart and a text "loading" in the bottom of the page. Does anyone of you know how to fix it? It works fine with simple jQuery and with jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 but I would like to have the newest version.

Here's the chart function:

```
$(function() {
    var datasets = {
        "usa": {
            label: "USA",
            data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
        },        
        "russia": {
            label: "Russia",
            data: [[1988, 218000], [1989, 203000], [1990, 171000], [1992, 42500], [1993, 37600], [1994, 36600], [1995, 21700], [1996, 19200], [1997, 21300], [1998, 13600], [1999, 14000], [2000, 19100], [2001, 21300], [2002, 23600], [2003, 25100], [2004, 26100], [2005, 31100], [2006, 34700]]
        },
        "uk": {
            label: "UK",
            data: [[1988, 62982], [1989, 62027], [1990, 60696], [1991, 62348], [1992, 58560], [1993, 56393], [1994, 54579], [1995, 50818], [1996, 50554], [1997, 48276], [1998, 47691], [1999, 47529], [2000, 47778], [2001, 48760], [2002, 50949], [2003, 57452], [2004, 60234], [2005, 60076], [2006, 59213]]
        },
        "germany": {
            label: "Germany",
            data: [[1988, 55627], [1989, 55475], [1990, 58464], [1991, 55134], [1992, 52436], [1993, 47139], [1994, 43962], [1995, 43238], [1996, 42395], [1997, 40854], [1998, 40993], [1999, 41822], [2000, 41147], [2001, 40474], [2002, 40604], [2003, 40044], [2004, 38816], [2005, 38060], [2006, 36984]]
        },
        "denmark": {
            label: "Denmark",
            data: [[1988, 3813], [1989, 3719], [1990, 3722], [1991, 3789], [1992, 3720], [1993, 3730], [1994, 3636], [1995, 3598], [1996, 3610], [1997, 3655], [1998, 3695], [1999, 3673], [2000, 3553], [2001, 3774], [2002, 3728], [2003, 3618], [2004, 3638], [2005, 3467], [2006, 3770]]
        },
        "sweden": {
            label: "Sweden",
            data: [[1988, 6402], [1989, 6474], [1990, 6605], [1991, 6209], [1992, 6035], [1993, 6020], [1994, 6000], [1995, 6018], [1996, 3958], [1997, 5780], [1998, 5954], [1999, 6178], [2000, 6411], [2001, 5993], [2002, 5833], [2003, 5791], [2004, 5450], [2005, 5521], [2006, 5271]]
        },
        "norway": {
            label: "Norway",
            data: [[1988, 4382], [1989, 4498], [1990, 4535], [1991, 4398], [1992, 4766], [1993, 4441], [1994, 4670], [1995, 4217], [1996, 4275], [1997, 4203], [1998, 4482], [1999, 4506], [2000, 4358], [2001, 4385], [2002, 5269], [2003, 5066], [2004, 5194], [2005, 4887], [2006, 4891]]
        }
    };

    // hard-code color indices to prevent them from shifting as
    // countries are turned on/off

    var i = 0;
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        val.color = i;
        ++i;
    });

    // insert checkboxes 
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
            "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
            "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
            + val.label + "</label>");
    });

    choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);

    function plotAccordingToChoices() {

        var data = [];

        choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
            var key = $(this).attr("name");
            if (key && datasets[key]) {
                data.push(datasets[key]);
            }
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
            $.plot("#placeholder", data, {
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickDecimals: 0
                }
            });
        }
    }

    plotAccordingToChoices();

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer

    $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
});
```

Comment: You should create a jsFiddle example and then we can take a look. Because this is not enough for us to give you a definite answer. jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/DthMC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with border/frame was not with jQuery Mobile, it was rather a Flot configuration. And loading msg can be fixed with a proper script initialization, Flot needs to be initialize after a jQuery Mobile.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/52cKB/

Frame was solved like this:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", data, {
    yaxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    xaxis: {
        tickDecimals: 0
    },
    grid: {
      borderWidth: 0
    }                     
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. There was a need to add jquery css in my project code